# Transaction function argument type

Tags: prisma, prisma-transaction

I want to use `$transaction` but I don't know what type I should pass to Prisma so that it provides me with type checking and autocompletion for models.

```
export default async function SignUp(data: SIGNUP_INTERFACE) {
  try {
    let user = await prisma.$transaction(async (prisma: any /* <- this */) => {
      let encrypted_password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10);
      // 1. Add user to database
      const user = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          username: data.username,
          password: encrypted_password,
        },
      });

      // 2. Add email/phone number to database
      if (data.phoneNumber) {
        await prisma.user_phone.create({
          data: { phone_number: data.phoneNumber },
        });
      }
      if (data.email) {
        await prisma.user_email.create({
          data: { email: data.email },
        });
      }
    });

    return user;
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw new CustomError(err.message);
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, never, Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined>
```

but then it gives

> Type '(prisma: PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>) => Promise<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'PrismaPromise[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more

Comment: Is there a problem to use `PrismaClient` as the type? The 3.0.2 client with `interactiveTransactions` enabled (which is something that I assume you have as well?) generates the type definition as `Omit<PrismaClient, '$connect' | '$disconnect' | '$on' | '$transaction' | '$use'>`, so `PrismaClient` is compatible with that as well.

Comment: ahh , I hadn't . My bad .Yep , that works . Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you solved this issue. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: in .prisma `interactiveTransactions` should be allowed ,```generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}```

Answer (score 4):

As it turned out from the comments, the `interactiveTransactions` flag should have been enabled to allow for the new transaction style, which in turn enabled to use `PrismaClient` as the type for `prisma`.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue but after digging out the transaction client should be typed as `Prisma.TransactionClient`, in your case `prisma: any` became `prisma: Prisma.TransactionClient`.
Hope this will help someone on the future.